# Inserting decoded string into 4 different columns

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a csv file like this.

```
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4
```

My input to the procedure will be the encoded form of that csv file i,e; MSwyLDMsNAoxLDIsMyw0CjEsMiwzLDQ=.

So now it should go like this

```
column_1  column_2  column_3  column_4
1          2        3         4
1          2        3         4
1          2        3         4
```

I was able to decode but I am inserting it into a single column like this and not able to insert it into different column

```
column_1  column_2  column_3  column_4
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4
```

The code that I wrote to decode and insert is as follows but I am unable to get the logic correct to insert into 4 different columns

```
 PROCEDURE try(P_ENCODED_STRING IN CLOB,truncateflag in varchar2) IS 
output varchar2(30000);
BEGIN
if (truncateflag='true') then
execute immediate 'truncate table demo';
end if;
output:=utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(utl_encode.base64_decode(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(P_ENCODED_STRING)));
insert into demo(column_1,column_2,column_3,column_4)
select regexp_substr(output, '[^'||CHR(10)||CHR(13)||']+', 1, level)
from dual
connect by regexp_substr(output, '[^'||CHR(10)||CHR(13)||']+', 1, level) is not null;
end try;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PROCEDURE LOAD_SPM_ITEM_SYNC(P_ENCODED_STRING IN CLOB,truncateflag in varchar2) IS 
r_records varchar2(3000);
BEGIN
declare
cursor c_records IS
select regexp_substr(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(utl_encode.base64_decode(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(P_ENCODED_STRING))), '[^'||CHR(10)||CHR(13)||']+', 1, level)
from dual 
connect by regexp_substr(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(utl_encode.base64_decode(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(P_ENCODED_STRING))), '[^'||CHR(10)||CHR(13)||']+', 1, level) is not null ;
Begin
 OPEN c_records;
 loop
  FETCH c_records INTO r_records; 
  exit when c_records%NOTFOUND;
insert into  demo(column_1,column_2,column_3,column_4)
select  
regexp_substr(r_records, '\d+', 1, 1) ,
regexp_substr(r_records, '\d+', 1, 2) ,
regexp_substr(r_records, '\d+', 1, 3) ,
regexp_substr(r_records, '\d+', 1, 4)
from dual;
end loop;
End;
--loop
end LOAD_SPM_ITEM_SYNC;
```

This code will convert encoded string to values and they will be inserted into 4 columns and we can add a new regex_substsr if we want a new column.

Answer (score 2):

Your insert has 2 issues. Assuming the string '1,2,3,4' is the result of your decode (not at all clear on that) there is no new line ( chr(10)||chr(13) ) data in it. As a result there is only 1 value to be extracted. Perhaps the decoded result is actually a CSV. I proceed with that assumption.  
Your second issue is that the regexp parse routine produces 4 rows, not 4 columns. You will have to somehow convert those rows to columns before inserting. The most "natural" way to do that is the PIVOT operator. Note for demonstration I changed your data values from '1,2,3,4' to 'A,B,C,D'. See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2197bc4ed7ce4738dd2e6e6fb313b830).

```
insert into demo(col1,col2,col3,col4)                
with decoded(res) as
     ( select 'A,B,C,D' from dual)
select * 
  from (select level lev
             , regexp_substr(res,'[^,]+', 1, level) itm  
          from decoded
        connect by regexp_substr(res, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null)
pivot (
         max(itm)
         for lev 
         in (1,2,3,4)
      );
```

Comment: my output after decoding will be (1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4) I mean it comes in a single line. So I had to use ( chr(10)||chr(13) ) such that after (1,2,3,4) is inserted one line I am going into a new line to Insert (1,2,3,4) again. Also, my code output will be in 3 different rows with (1,2,3,4) in column_1 and empty values in column_2, ...column_4. Now I want (1,2,3,4) in each of the 4 columns as mentioned in the question.

Comment: if my input is just (A,B,C,D) I can use pivot and convert row to column But I will be having 1000's of (A,B,C,D) and in that case I think pivot will not be helpful.